# How should I make this routing RESTful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

For RESTful purpose, I made my routing just like this:

**routes.rb**

```
match 'shops/:sort/:genre/:area', :to => 'shops#index'
```

But what if genre was empty? 
Isn't it going to redirect to `example.com/shops/newest_first//california`?

How can I solve this kind of routing and parameters problem?
Can anyone show me good example?

**view**

```
<%= form_tag shops_path, :method => :get do %>
    <%= select_tag :sort, options_from_collection_for_select(Sort.all, 'id', 'name', params[:sort]), :prompt => "Newest first" %>
    <%= select_tag :genre, options_from_collection_for_select(Genre.all, 'id', 'name', params[:genre]), :prompt => "all" %>
    <%= select_tag :area, options_from_collection_for_select(Area.all, 'id', 'name', params[:area]), :prompt => "all" %>
<% end %>
```

**Another View**

Comment: Your route is **not** REST-ful. I think you misunderstand what that means. Also, submitting your form is not going to generate a URL matching your route **ever**. Instead it will point to `/shops?sort=...&genre=...&area=...`, and yes `...` may be blank for any of them if your select lists contain a blank option. If you're doing `GET` form submissions it will always generate a querystring, and it's in part for the issue you're bringing up that what you're trying to do with your route isn't the best idea.

Comment: I would say just validate your form that the param is never missing. Or set a default value if its missing. You could build it this way yes, but i agree with the answer from "Erez Rabih" set it up as parameters is the more common way

Comment: Thanks guys. What do you think Erez's answer? Would you guys do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While restful routing is the most intuitive and conventional, it does not always fit our needs.

In your case I'd suggest using query parameters instead of a strict restful route.

`example.com/shops` will receive 3 query parameters: `sort`, `genre` and `area`, so a URL may look like `example.com/shops?area=california&sort=newest_first`

The in the index action of you controller you can query for the existence of these parameters in the following manner:

```
def index
  if !params[:sort].blank?
    @shops = @shops.sort(params[:sort])
  end
  if !params[:area].blank?
    @shops = @shops.where(:area => params[:area])
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

This way you are well protected against missing parameters in your controller, but still you are able to supply whatever data the user requests.

On a side note: be sure to check that the `params` hash you're using contains only values you are willing to accept.

Comment: Thank you so much. In my case, so I don't need to follow my way? For SEO purpose, I was thinking that your war is better for google search engine because they can judge it's parameters. But if I did my way, google search engine might misunderstand they are different pages.  So In my situation, your way is the best solution. right?

Comment: In my opinion yes, you may get here another answer which might be better.